# How to make threads wait until initialization of a variable?

Tags: java, java-threads

I am creating a List of 10 objects of type java.sql.Connection in my main method to implement ConnectionPool. Then I am creating 10 threads which will use these connections for query execution and then release them. Problem which I am facing is that in my functions where I remove Connection from one list and add them to other list. More than one thread reach their and they try to take Connection object from list and my list throws IndexOutOfBoundsException as it can not delete element from a 0 sized list.

My code is as follows:
`public Connection getConnection() { Connection c=cList.remove(cList.size()-1); usedList.add(c); }`

I am getting IndexOutOfBoundsException in remove function for few threads.

Is there any problem with my code or threads are working faster than creation of objects?

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason why you are creating connection pool instead of using Hikari or C3P0. Try them unless you have a specific requirement

Comment: Don't use a `List`, use a `Queue`. Don't use a regular one, use a `Concurrent` one, which is *thread-safe*. Since you're attempting to write multi-threaded code, and obviously don't understand about thread-safety, I **highly recommend** you read up on the topic now, before continuing to write multi-threaded code.

Comment: @Andreas I agree, writing code is easy, writing _concurrent_ code is hard.

Comment: @SamDJava I am writing this code as initial step to teach students about connection pool.  On next step I will move to Apache DBCP or Hikari may be.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks a lot Andreas. I wrote this code as first step to teach students about concurrency but even after putting this code block in synchronized block I am facing the same problem. Shouldn't it be solved in that case?

Comment: @SanjeetKumar If the code moving a connection object from `cList` to `usedList`, and the code moving the object back from `usedList` to `cList` are both protected by the a `synchronized` block in the same object, as well as any other code that uses `cList` and/or `usedList`, then you shouldn't have trouble. Is *ALL* the code using those two lists protected the same?